# Google maps Marker dissapear after zoom in function

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi Im working with HTML5 and I have a simple js function where i set the center of my map and the zoom:

```
function goToMaxZoom(){
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(12.32323, -3.683639) );
    map.setZoom(16);}
```

everything is going good except for the map markers, they are not displayed

i tryed also to add:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

to make a new one but it doesnt work, even if i add the whole marker build:

```
 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);
 var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
 position:(12.32323, -3.683639),
 });
```

So i think im missing something.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an object of LatLng before adding it to the marker as shown below

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.32323, -3.683639)

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
```

You can also create the LatLng object using the following constructor

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 12.32323, lng: -3.683639});
```

OR

```
var myLatLng = {lat: 12.32323, lng: -3.683639};
```

All three are valid ways to create a LatLng object

Comment: So "position:" doesnt accept (lat,long). Thanks man for the quick answer!

Comment: Also i forgot to add map properties to the constructor in the function.

Comment: @Jnewbie You can use (lat, long) but you need to create an object: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044} (Use "{}" instead of "()")